# How to add a service to settings menu?

Tags: android, service, settings, manifest, foreground-service

I want to add a service to the android settings screen to implement a somehow similar feature as the application **'Accessability Scanner'**.

Launcher appear in the same Location when setting the category to **android.intent.category.HOME**.

Is there something similar I can tell the Service in the manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of Service is called [AccessibilityService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService)